# Clicker Hero Problem With Ascending

Tags: clicker-heroes

On clicker heroes, I accidentally ascended. Is there any way I can undo that?

I have tried to restart it but it didn't work.

Comment: Just wanted to remind you that if an answer was helpful for you, you should click the little tick icon next to it to mark it as the accepted answer. That way, anyone else who sees this question immediately knows that answer works.

Answer (score 3):

You can not undo an ascension (without prep*). You will just have to continue playing. Hopefully you gained a few Hero Souls which should make your current run go a bit faster, which is ultimately your goal anyway. Play for a while, gain some Hero Souls, Ascend, rinse/repeat.

*If you have a backup save from before your ascension you could just load in that save. To save your game press the Wrench in the top right corner. To then import that save just press the Import button directly below it and select your save file.